# Removing permissions from a sharepoint folder in a for loop

Tags: powershell

I am trying to remove all the permissions from folders in sharepoint using a powershell script but only some of the permissions are being removed.  When I manually run the powershell commands I can see that there are four role assignmebers but only two are removed.

```
PS C:\support\scripts> $rvn.Item.RoleAssignments.Count
4
PS C:\support\scripts> for($i=0;$i -lt $rvn.Item.RoleAssignments.Count; $i++){
>> $ra = $rvn.Item.RoleAssignments[$i]
>> write-host "$i $($ra.Member.LoginName)"
>> }
>>
0 Microsoft CRM Visitors
1 rmvd\timc
2 rmvd\amyw
3 rmvd\AaronR
PS C:\support\scripts> for($i=0;$i -lt $rvn.Item.RoleAssignments.Count; $i++){
>> $ra = $rvn.Item.RoleAssignments[$i]
>> write-host "$i $($ra.Member.LoginName)"
>> $rvn.Item.RoleAssignments.Remove($ra.Member)
>> }
>>
0 Microsoft CRM Visitors
1 rmvd\amyw
PS C:\support\scripts>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You remove `Microsoft CRM Visitors`, and `rmvd\timc` becomes `RoleAssignments[0]`. So in the next iteration you remove `RoleAssignments[1]` which is now `rmvd\amyw`. `RoleAssignments[2]` is now empty.

You need to either always remove the last entry, or do this using a `while` loop.

Comment: That makes sense.  I did not think about the fact that I was modifying the collection I was looping over.  Thank you